# Firebase notification works even with no service or inherited class?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I implemented firebase into my app to use it's notification service a while back and it worked, and today decided to use it's key/value feature, but realized that no matter what I write in my class inherited from `FirebaseMessagingService`, nothing happens. So I decided to remove the my class for dubugging purposes, and I still got notifications. So I removed the firebase messaging service from the manifest, deleted the app cache and ran the project, but I still get notifications! The only way I can prevent notifications from coming is to remove the firebase dependency in gradle. What's happening here?

Comment: I can help but you have to provide some code, for example your service declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml`. And what about your "notifications": are there notification messages or messages with both notification and data payload?

Answer (score 1):

Just [**read the documentation**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

...

Ok, let's go: there are three kind of "notification" using Firebase: *notification messages*, *data messages* and *messages with both notification and data*. Each is received and handled differently by the system. [**Here**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) you can see more information about message types (how there are built).

There are handled like that:

- *Notification message*

  - App in foreground: `onMessageReceived`'s implementation
  - App in background: system tray (system dispatch automatically notification) -> **with or without service implementation** (maybe your case, without code I can't know)
- *Data message*

  - App in foreground: `onMessageReceived`'s implementation
  - App in background: `onMessageReceived`'s implementation
- *Message with both notification and data*

  - App in foreground: `onMessageReceived`'s implementation
  - App in background: system tray (notification) and in extras of the intent (data)

But without any code or notification information, I can't continue to help you. Until you provide some code example, I only think that you send a *notification message*, and so system automatically display a notification and there is no call to the service's `onMessageReceived`, it's normal.

If you want to "control" and decide if notification should be shown or not, just send *data messages*, and in your `onMessageReceived` implementation, create a notification with content and intent and *notify* it to the system (if you want it to be shown).