# FCM Notification not received (on Galaxy S8 and One-Plus 3) if app is closed or removed from Task Manager

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, android-manifest, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM (Firebase Notification) and everything is working fine on all devices except Samsung Galaxy S8 and One-Plus 3

When application running in foreground/background everything is working perfectly

But when I Remove the application from Task Manager (Swipe-Tray) or finish the application using `backPress()` devices stop receiving notification,

My complete code of service and manifest.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (!remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("subtitle")) {
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
                String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
                String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");
                String rideId = remoteMessage.getData().get("ride_id");
                String rideName = remoteMessage.getData().get("ride_name");
                String ridePic = remoteMessage.getData().get("ride_pic");

                MessageDTO messageDTO = new MessageDTO();
                messageDTO.setRideId(Integer.parseInt(rideId));
                messageDTO.setRideName(rideName);
                messageDTO.setRidePic(ridePic);
                messageDTO.setMessage(message);
                // Don't show notification if chat activity is open.
                if (!AppController.isChatActivityOpen()) {
                    sendNotification(title, messageDTO);
                } else {
                    //EventBus.getDefault().post(new PushNotificationEvent(title, message, username, uid, fcmToken));
                }
            }
        }
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */
    private boolean sendNotification(String title, MessageDTO messageDTO) {
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SelectedChannel", messageDTO);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageDTO.getMessage())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
        int returnValue = 0;

        return returnValue == 1 ? true : false;

    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
    android:name="main.cyclesoon.com.chat.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My server side code :

```
public class FcmNotificationBuilder {
    public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    private static final String TAG = "FcmNotificationBuilder";
    private static final String SERVER_API_KEY = "server_key";
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
    private static final String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTH_KEY = "key=" + SERVER_API_KEY;
    private static final String FCM_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    // json related keys
    //private static final String KEY_TO = "to";
    private static final String KEY_TO = "registration_ids";

    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";
    //private static final String KEY_DATA = "data";
    private static final String KEY_DATA = "notification";
    private static final String KEY_RIDE_ID = "ride_id";
    private static final String KEY_RIDE_NAME = "ride_name";
    private static final String KEY_RIDE_PIC = "ride_pic";

    private String mTitle;
    private String mMessage;
    private JSONArray mReceiverFirebaseToken;
    private String mRideId;
    private String mRideName;
    private String mRidePic;

    private FcmNotificationBuilder() {
    }

    public static FcmNotificationBuilder initialize() {
        return new FcmNotificationBuilder();
    }

    public FcmNotificationBuilder title(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
        return this;
    }

    public FcmNotificationBuilder message(String message) {
        mMessage = message;
        return this;
    }

    public FcmNotificationBuilder setRideInfo(String rideId, String rideName, String ridePic) {
        mRideId = rideId;
        mRideName = rideName;
        mRidePic = ridePic;
        return this;
    }

    public FcmNotificationBuilder receiverFirebaseToken(JSONArray receiverFirebaseToken) {
        mReceiverFirebaseToken = receiverFirebaseToken;
        return this;
    }

    public void send() {
        RequestBody requestBody = null;
        try {
            requestBody = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON, getValidJsonBody().toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
                .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_KEY)
                .url(FCM_URL)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        Call call = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "onGetAllUsersFailure: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().string());
            }
        });
    }

    private JSONObject getValidJsonBody() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObjectBody = new JSONObject();
        ///JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        //jsonArray.put(mReceiverFirebaseToken);
        //jsonArray.put("fPMLS022iPE:APA91bEBJjgUDN-mSPtZjS4EtWT_DGnTmajc8gaWJUjULjodPrq9OUvhSHc3Lkk1Mxx8Z_b6g6NpJhKqe0WxZETz6vpnAxL2UnYU5qZYM2u0YEZdF0JgX0bD0jViqi6guKmwE_rss2CK");
        //jsonObjectBody.put(KEY_TO, mReceiverFirebaseToken);
        jsonObjectBody.put(KEY_TO, mReceiverFirebaseToken);
        JSONObject jsonObjectData = new JSONObject();
        jsonObjectData.put(KEY_TITLE, mTitle);
        jsonObjectData.put(KEY_TEXT, mMessage);
        jsonObjectData.put(KEY_RIDE_ID, mRideId);
        jsonObjectData.put(KEY_RIDE_NAME, mRideName);
        jsonObjectData.put(KEY_RIDE_PIC, mRidePic);
        jsonObjectBody.put(KEY_DATA, jsonObjectData);

        return jsonObjectBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Android version of these devices? Does `AppController.isChatActivityOpen()` has a particular implementation and/or a version dependent implementation?

Comment: Yes this happens ! If you remove your app from task manager then this FCM service class is also killed ! Same thing happens with Mi phones !

Comment: I explained different kind of Firebase messages here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45015683/6523232 . You can see for each messages where it is triggered. What kind of Firebase messages are you using?

Comment: @N0un Nougat 7.0  `AppController.isChatActivityOpen()` is only to check activity is visible or not

Comment: @AkhileshPatil In my previous comment I send you an answer that explain how Firebase messages are different. I use data messages and it works even if my app is killed manually from task manager.

Comment: @N0un thanks, let me try

Comment: @N0un I tried data tag as well as notification tag but none of this working.

Comment: @AkhileshPatil Ok, could you try to put a `sendNotification("title", "body");` call as the first instruction of the `onMessageReceived` function and test with data message again?

Comment: @N0un i have comment out all the code inside `onMessageReceived` and put `sendNotification("title", "body")`; but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150062/discussion-between-n0un-and-akhilesh-patil).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504805/android-app-not-receiving-firebase-notification-when-app-is-stopped-from-multi-t)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, check the answer and ref the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FCM sends notification in two forms inside **data** tag and another one in **notification tag**. When the app is open the **data** is triggered and when the app is cleared from the background, FCM tries to handle the notification on its own using **notification** tag. What you can do is by asking the server guy only to send with data as a key and not notification. Then you can handle the notification.

For more information read this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded)

Comment: If server guy send notification with data as a key and if application is killed from task manager then it wont work !

Comment: @rushankshah Yes it works (by experience). Please read the referenced link. Furthermore, I made an answer that explain the different kind of Firebase messages here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45015683/6523232

Comment: No it not works on Mi, huawei and many chinese devices ! 
Even sometime it wont work on Lenovo phones ! All these phones has inbuilt task killer option in recent app . So when i press task killer button then all application and its services will be killed and will not get any notification.

Comment: @rushankshah Ok, I didn't know that (I easily can expect that). But I think there is an other issue here because of the Samsung Galaxy S8. I had some problem with Samsung but Android's Services are a important part of the system and it is weird that Samsung fails with it for latest phone.

Comment: @N0un i am not saying that your explanation is wrong on FCM ! That's 100% correct but it wont work with many chinese devices !

Comment: @rushankshah Yes I understand, thanks ^^ Just I expect that it should works on S8 isn't it?

Comment: @N0un yes it should !