# How to receive FCM notification if app is totally closed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send both data-message and notification-message and it works well when the app is in foreground and background.

But I'm not able to receive any message if I close it from window manager(by swiping) Is there any way to make achieve that?

Comment: What specific device are you testing on?

Comment: same prob with me on S8 and One-Plus3

Comment: My question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296446/fcm-notification-not-received-on-galaxy-s8-and-one-plus-3-if-app-is-closed-or

Comment: @CommonsWare Asus with auto-start manager and Huawei with protected app manager

Comment: On the Huawei device, have you tried making your app protected by to going to _Battery Manager > Protected Apps_.  I don't have a Huawei device, but have seen this described in other posts, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31638986/4815718

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829) for some possibly helpful details.